# Specifying A Dynamic Type In Swift Generics

Tags: swift, generics

I created a small wrapper class for `NSNotification` registrations.

```
public final class EventRegistration<E: AppEvent> {
private(set) var event: E?
private var token: AnyObject?

public init() {}

public init(event: E, token: AnyObject) {
    self.event = event
    self.token = token
}

public func unregister() {
    if let token = self.token,
       let event = self.event {
        event.unregister(token)
    }
    token = nil
    event = nil
}

public var isRegistered: Bool {
    return token != nil
}

deinit {
    unregister()
}
}
```

It is a simple enough class. Now I would like to return it from a method on the **base class** of all my other events. Here is the signature:

```
public class AppEvent : CustomStringConvertible {
         public func register(notification: (NSNotification! -> Void))->EventRegistration {
    let eventName = self.dynamicType.eventName()

    let token = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(eventName, object: nil, queue: self.dynamicType.eventQueue(), usingBlock: notification)

    let registration = EventRegistration(event: self, token: token)

    return registration
}
```

The question, is what can I put for the return type of `register` such that I get the correct `AppEvent` subclass when this method is called on subclass.

ie.

```
class SomeSubClass: AppEvent {}
```

I would want `result.event` to be of type `SomeSubClass`